# Styling the UIPopOverViewController

Tags: ipad, ios4

I've seen a few apps on the iPad recently adding a bit of design to the pop overs.
Does anyone have any pointers on how you would go about changing the pop overs design without writing your own?

I'm hoping to achieve something like the pop overs in iBook or Calcbot.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to really customize the UIPopoverController. You can write your own pretty easily though.